# How to correctly apply Python absolute value to a list to avoid an TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Tags: python, cryptography

I have following piece of logic

```
def extended_gcd(aa, bb):
    lastremainder, remainder = abs(aa), abs(bb)
    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while remainder:
        lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder, divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
        x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
        y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
    return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if aa < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if bb < 0 else 1)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = extended_gcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise ValueError
    return x % m

N = 0x00249difuv994924942323

A = 0x0000000000024224234234
B = ["0xd4c19erfiorf434434", "0xd4c19eirjfrf434434"]

print (h(((A) * modinv(B,N)) % N))
```

in B i need to use list, but I can't find a workaround for TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'. Following the documentation of ABS I tried to use map() and list() function to convert it to the absolute value,

```
map(abs(bb))...
```

but without success.

How to do this correctly? I am trying to learn different applications of the extended Euclid algorithm.

Comment: `map(abs,bb)`??

Comment: like this, remainder = abs(aa), map(abs(bb)). 
https://appdividend.com/2022/07/27/python-absolute-value/

Comment: You are calling `modinv()` with two arguments, the *first* of which is a list. In `modinv` itself, that  first argument is called `a`, so it is a list. Then `modinv` calls `extended_gcd` and passes `a` (the list) to it as its first argument. So in `extended_gcd`, it is `aa` that is a list, not `bb`. The problem is that both `modinv` and `extended_gcd` expect numerical arguments and are not at all prepared to deal with lists. So why are you calling `modinv` with a list argument? You could e.g. loop over the list and call `modinv` with each element - no need for `map`.

Comment: hello Nick, thanks for clarifying! Actually tried to use 'map' because I don't know any other way to do it. Please, could you clarify a little about 'loop over the list and call modinv with each element'? Any hints on how to implement this down correctly?